# Video Splash does not center on the screen - Android Studio

Tags: android, video, screen, center, splash-screen

I have seen something similar here, but I could not solve with the solutions given. I am trying to start a video as splash screen in an Android Studio project, it is launched at the beginning correctly but it is not centered in the middle of the screen, it is at the top, what am I doing wrong? In the project itself does not appear any error and everything works normal, it is only the video that does not centralize. NOTE: I do not have much experience with Android Studio, so if there is something meaningless in the code, please correct me.

androidmanifest.xml:

```
...

<!-- Activities -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.sherdle.universal.splash_demo"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sherdle.universal.MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".providers.yt.player.YouTubePlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>

...
```

splash_demo.java:

```
...

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;

/**
 * Created by rmm on 12/7/2016.
 */

public class splash_demo extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle sa){
        super.onCreate(sa);
        try{
            VideoView videoView = new VideoView(this);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
            Uri path = Uri.parse( "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+ +R.raw.vid1);
videoView.setVideoURI(path);

            videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    jump();
                }


            });
videoView.start();
        }catch (Exception e){
            jump();
        }



    }
    private void jump() {

        if(isFinishing())
            return;
        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

activity_splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_splash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context="com.sherdle.universal.splash_demo">


    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/videoView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing LinearLayout  with Relative  Layout with VideoView attribute android:layout_centerInParent="true"

Comment: Sorry, I have little experience, I added the Relative Layout, but I do not know where to insert layout_centerInParent = "true", could you tell the way?

Comment: @nauvaro 

<VideoView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
Android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:id="@+id/videoView" />

Comment: I followed the steps, but now the screen is all black and nothing happens

Comment: actually the black background is the default background of the VideoView as it took the whole layout.
There are some issues with the code itself to play the video,
1 - you should `VideoView videoView = (VideoView) VideoView(r.id.videoView); `
 rather than `VideoView videoView = new VideoView(this);`
2 - you should assign the uri to the videoView as `videoView.setVideoURI(path);`
3- finally you have to call `videoView.start();`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help now worked perfectly, actually with only one exception, a message appears in the Studio saying: Instant Run performed a full build and install since the installation on the device does not match the local build on disk. I'm not sure what it means, other than having little English fluency, I'm new to Android Studio, as I mentioned earlier. Do I need to correct something so this message does not appear?